# Define passport strategy in a separate file and use it across the app

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I've been trying this for quite a while, but I just can't seem to get a hang of how this works.

I have a `passport.ts` file which roughly is defined as:

```
passport.serializeUser<any, any>((user, done) => {
    done(undefined, 1);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    done(null, 1);
});

// Strategy config
const GoogleStrategy = passportGoogle.Strategy
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.get('googleAuth.clientID'),
    clientSecret: config.get('googleAuth.clientSecret'),
    callbackURL: config.get('googleAuth.callbackURL'),
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)=> {
    return done
}))
```

In the root directory of the project, I have an `index.ts` which does the standard passport initialization:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I'm defining controllers via express's Router function in different files, one of which is `authenticate.ts` which is roughly along these lines:

```
import {Router} from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import config from 'config';
import * as passportConfig from '../utils/passport' //this is passport.ts which was pasted above
const router = Router();

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {scope: config.get('googleAuth.scope')}));
```

I understand that I am missing the callback route, but I had issues making this work as I am unsure as to how the passport object defined in passport.ts with the strategy can be used in different files.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I understood, you want to define your passport strategy in a separate file and use them. For that you can do something like this

Create a file to define your strategy `google-strategy.ts`

```
const googleStrategy = new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.get('googleAuth.clientID'),
    clientSecret: config.get('googleAuth.clientSecret'),
    callbackURL: config.get('googleAuth.callbackURL'),
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)=> {
    return done
})
module.exports = googleStrategy;
```

and in your `passport.ts` file

```
const googleStrategy = require('./google-strategy');
// giving a name to a strategy so we can refer it in routes
passport.use('MyGoogleStrategy', googleStrategy);
```

and in your `authenticate.ts` file

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('MyGoogleStrategy', {scope: config.get('googleAuth.scope')}));
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying @Naresh! I had one question, for all routes would I have to import the passport.ts file? i.e how does the authenticate.ts file access the passport object with the google strategy in it?